# how to write contents for linked list to a file

Tags: c++, file-io, std

I have a write function which im using to write the contents of a list to a file. The list contains only numbers.

```
list<int>::iterator pos;
    for (pos = listStorage.begin(); pos != listStorage.end(); ++pos)
    {
        out << *pos << endl;
    }
    return out;
```

I am getting an error on compilation;

> error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::list<_Ty>::_Const_iterator<_Secure_validation>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: does it work if you comment out the output statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is a const issue.  Is your listStorage object declared as const?  If so, you need to declare your iterator as

```
const list<int>::iterator pos;
```

Comment: I declared my listStorage as, list<int> listStorage;

Comment: Looks like a constness issue to me- for example, if it's in a const member function.

Comment: What happens if you change `list<int>::iterator` to `list<int>::const_iterator`?

Comment: Is is an incorrect solution and will only cause additional compilation issues. You'd declaring `pos` to be constant, not an iterator on a const `list`. You should follow @Kristopher Johnson's fix. Until updated, -1.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than an explicit loop, I'd use an algorithm:

```
std::copy(listStorage.cbegin(), listStorage.cend(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, "\n"));
```

This will probably prevent the problem you're seeing, and incidentally clean up the code and almost certainly run faster as well (though the speedup with come from using `"\n"` instead of `endl`).

Comment: Why `cbegin` and `cend`? Do they exist?

Comment: yes, good point, cbegin and cend do not exist in the std::list

Comment: @Nawaz, `cbegin`/`cend` are new in C++11 (aka C++0x).

Comment: @Nawaz: because we're not planning to modify the contents. They're new with C++11, so they exist, if only in relatively recent compilers. If yours doesn't support them, just use `begin` and `end` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/179828

it discusses the same issue as yours.